# Custom validation attribute is never validated

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I am trying to create a custom validation attribute to only require a field depending on the result of another.

The problem I am having is that the IsValid block is never called. The data seems to be getting into the fields and I have been able to check this with a breakpoint.

I tried putting a `TryValidateModel(this)` in the `OnPostAsync` and this worked through the breakpoint but I could see that another error occurred.

> The requested operation is invalid for DynamicMethod

Here is my code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        public class PageOneModel : PageModel
        {
            [BindProperty]
            public bool CompanyHouseToggle { get; set; }

            [BindProperty]
            [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
            [RequiredIf("CompanyHouseToggle", desiredvalue: "true")]
            public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }

            [BindProperty]
            [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
            public string OrganisationName { get; set; }

            [BindProperty]
            [RegularExpression(pattern: "(GB)?([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})", ErrorMessage = "This VAT number is not recognised")]
            public string VatNumber { get; set; }

            public void OnGet()
            {
            }

            public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return Page();
                }

                RedirectToPage("2");
            }
        }

        public class RequiredIfAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute
        {
            private String PropertyName { get; set; }
            private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

            public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
            {
                this.PropertyName = propertyName;
                this.DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
            }

            protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
            {
                var property = context.ObjectType.GetProperty(PropertyName);

                if (property == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Property with this name not found");

                // Just for testing purposes.
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to inherit from the ReuiredAttribute. It fully works for me.

```
public class RequiredUnlessDeletingAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    string DeletingProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the object is going to be deleted skip the validation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deletingProperty">The boolean property`s name which shows the object will be deleted.</param>
    public RequiredUnlessDeletingAttribute(string deletingProperty = "MustBeDeleted") =>
        DeletingProperty = deletingProperty;

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(deletingProperty);

        if ((bool)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance))
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);

    }
}
```

Check the full implementation [here](https://github.com/Geeksltd/Olive/blob/master/Mvc/Olive.Mvc/Attributes/RequiredUnlessDeletingAttribute.cs)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have also tried this. You are right this means it does get called but the problem is now that it cannot find the property. It just comes back as null. Have you faced that problem before?

Thanks for your help though

Comment: Upon more research you are right, inheriting from ValidationAttribute will only trigger when the field has a value. Still stuck on this null property value though...

Comment: I have tested your code and nothing was wrong with it. Of course, I have removed **PageModel** and **OnPostAsync** and **OnGet** from it.

Comment: I have posted another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518325/c-sharp-unable-to-find-other-properties-in-custom-validation-attribute) as I hit another issue but marked this as resolved as you did fix my initial issue. Thanks